Why isn't it possible to chain .await in certain situations?
async fn get_students_with_upcoming_exam(
    State(state): State<Arc<AppState>>,
    Query(in_days): Query<u8>
) -> impl IntoResponse {
    // let students = state.state.read().await.students_with_upcoming_exam(in_days);
    let students_lock = state.state.read().await;
    let students = students_lock.students_with_upcoming_exam(in_days);
    (StatusCode::OK, Json(json!(students)))
}

In my axum handler I'm trying to use the students_with_upcoming_exam(u8) function which just filters the Vec of students on my shared state, which is DrivingSchool. For some reason if I don't split the await part with the part for calling the function, it won't compile. But when I split it like this it goes through. Why I can't do it in a single line, like the commented line above? What am I missing here? I want to understand why this is happening in depth.
(Don't mind the state.state, its just poor naming :) )
This is the error I'm getting:
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
   --> src\main.rs:121:20
    |
121 |     let students = state.state.read().await.students_with_upcoming_exam(in_days);
    |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                     - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
    |                    |
    |                    creates a temporary value which is freed while still in use
...
124 |     (StatusCode::OK, Json(json!(students)))
    |                           --------------- borrow later used here
    |
    = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value

Below is the relevant code I'm using for this case:
struct AppState {
    state: RwLock<DrivingSchool>,
}
...
pub struct DrivingSchool {
    pub students: Vec<Student>,
}
...
pub fn students_with_upcoming_exam(&self, in_days: u8) -> Vec<&Student> {
        let naive_in_days = Utc::now().naive_utc().checked_add_days(chrono::Days::new(in_days as u64)).unwrap().date();
        self.students
            .iter()
            .filter(|student| student.exam_date.is_some())
            .filter(|student| student.exam_date.unwrap() <= naive_in_days)
            .collect()
    }

When I split the command that awaits, it worked.

This isn't at all related to async/await and already discussed ad nauseam on this platform
